# Using filter: blur and contrast in style of elements

Tags: cytoscape.js

Can I change contrast and blur of nodes and edges in cytoscape? I try to use propetries: filter: blur(...) and filter: contrast(...) in style of elements, but this does not work. Please, help me change this properties of elements

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cy.nodes().style() function

```
cy.nodes("[id = '" + target.id() + "']").style('opacity', 0);  // node is invisible
cy.nodes("[id = '" + target.id() + "']").style('opacity', 0.5);  // node is half transparent
cy.nodes("[id = '" + target.id() + "']").style('opacity', 0);  // node is fully visible
```